# Does every infinite group has infinite cyclic subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

I need a help with determining if this statement is true or not.

> Does every infinite group has infinite cyclic subgroup?

Comment: see e.g. $(C_2)^{\mathbb Z}$ -every element has order $2$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Just take $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \ldots$.

Every element has finite order, so cannot generate an infinite group.

Answer (score 3):

In the infinite abelian group $(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,+)$ each element has finite order, for if $0<\frac pq<1\in \Bbb Q,\ p,q\in\Bbb N$, then $q\cdot \frac pq=p=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The **quasicyclic** $p$-group (the group of all radicals $\sqrt[p^n]{1}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{C}$) is infinite, but all its subgroups are finite cyclic.